# print longest input line.(example in K&R(2e)(section 1.9))

Tags: c

When I am executing this program (in ubuntu) and I enter input like `($ represents EOF(Ctrl+D)) :-`

```
giujb  
bjb $$
```

it does not work
but for the input

```
giujb       
bjb $$$
```

it works.

I think it should require to give EOF only twice (in this program). Can anyone explain why it requires to give EOF three times?

**My code**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define maxlength 1000
char line[maxlength];
char longest[maxlength];
int getlength();
void copy();
int main()
{
int max=0,leng=0;
while((leng=getlength())>0)
{ if(leng>max)
  {max=leng;
  copy();
  }
 } 
 if(max>0)
 printf("\n%s",longest);
 return 0;
 }
  int getlength()
 { char ch;
    int i;
    for(i=0;(i<(maxlength-1)) && ((ch=getchar())!= EOF) && (ch!='\n');++i)
    {line[i]=ch;
     printf("%d",i);
     }

    if(ch=='\n')
    {line[i]=ch;
     ++i;
     }
    line[i]='\0';
    printf("bye");
    return i;
    }
    void copy()
    {
    int i=0;
    while((longest[i]=line[i])!='\0')
    ++i;
    }
```

Comment: Your code is wrong — `getchar()` returns an integer value, so  `char ch;` should be `int ch;`

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, Ctrl-D does not mean End-Of-File (EOF). It means 'end-of-transmission', which means that the currently typed input is immediately sent to your program. It is similar to newline with the exception that Ctrl-D itself is not sent. Your `getchar` returns EOF when it receives  an empty "transmission". This is why you have to type Ctrl-D three times (or a newline followed by two Ctrl-D) to get two EOFs.

Comment: can u  tell me,what is EOF in linux. Is there  any concept of providing EOF or only empty transmission is consider as EOF

Comment: I don't think that you can actually end the standard input. What you can do is to invoke your program through a pipe. Type `cat | ./a.out`. In this case after a single empty transmission, `cat` will close its output and your program will receive EOFs only.